# Form Validating - double validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I need to validate a form, everything is working, except for one part.

I need to validate that if "remail" field is not filled, then it checks if "rsms" field is filled. 
AND VICE VERSA (if "rsms" field is filled, then check if "remail" field is filled)
If neither are filled, then return false, and alert that neither are filled.

I also need to validate that if BOTH "remail" and "rsms" fields are filled, it returns false and also alerts that you can only have one field filled!

CODE I'M USING FOR OTHER FIELDS:

```
var x=document.forms["form"]["remail"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("The Receivers Email field must be filled out!");
  return false;
  }
```

Please help,
Thanks,
Chad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var remail=document.forms["form"]["remail"].value;
var rsms=document.forms["form"]["rsms"].value;

if (remail==null && rsms ==null){
alert ("Both empty");
return false;
}
else if (remail !=null && rsms !=null){
alert ("Both fill");
}
```

Comment: Had to change a few things around such as add if `(remail==null && rsms==null || remail=="" && rsms=="")` to make it work. Thank you for the format though, got it to work!!

Comment: "I need to validate that if "remail" field is not filled, then it checks if "rsms" field is filled." <-- Your question's wording wan't clear. You asked specifically for variables to be checked in a certain order, not just if they both were empty or filled. Be more specific next time.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? (pardon the pseudo code)

```
if (remail != "") {
    if (rsms != "") {
        // RSMS & REMAIL ARE FILLED
    }
    else {
        // REMAIL IS FILLED, RSMS IS NOT
    }
}
else {
    if (rsms == "") {
        // RSMS & REMAIL ARE NOT FILLED
    }
    else {
        // REMAIL IS NOT FILLED, RSMS IS
    }
}
```

Comment: My point is, you're not just asking for certain variables to be checked, you're asking for them to be checked in a specific order. You have four options with 2 variables being filled or not filled. You're gonna have to build in 4 possible outcomes in your code if you want that ordering logic built-in.

Comment: Re-read what you wrote. Saying "Check for this, THEN this" is NOT the same as "Check both of these things." You implied that order of checking was important.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I still thank you for your answer.